# Handling an unstable reactive API

Tags: java, reactive-programming, normalization

I'm forced to use a custom library which contains methods that return a `Mono`,  however these same methods may occasionally return `null` or even throw an exception without it being wrapped into a `Mono.error`. I am aware this is highly ridiculous but it is the way it is and i don't have the luxury of rejecting this particular library.

Currently I've wrapped all library calls into my custom method which tries to normalize the response into a `Mono` instance:

```
public static <T> Mono<T> normalize(Supplier<Mono<T>> supplier) {
    try {
        Mono<T> result = supplier.get();
        return result != null ? result : Mono.empty();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        return Mono.error(ex);
    }
}

// Usage
Mono.just(...)
    .then(...)
    .then(normalize(() -> lib.call(...))
    .map(...)
    ...
```

I'm curious is there any built in way of normalizing any object into a mono while paying attention not to wrap an existing mono and to wrap exceptions into error Mono?

Comment: Not knowing of any builtin way, but this method seems the way to go. as it is clear what your trying to achieve